# Jquery sidebar slide out/in not working locally

Tags: javascript, jquery

Help! :)

So, 
I have been trying to add a slide-in cookiebox with jquery, 
it works perfectly on jsfiddle, 
but i can't make it work on local, 
it acts as if the library wasn't loaded and it just shows the box right away and the buttons dont do anything.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u2zz4/1/

How i load the scripts in the header(already checked that both paths are working correctly)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min2-0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cookiebox.js"></script>
```

The used Jquery lib is from https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js
(added the 2-0 behind it to remember its version, tested without 2-0 and it acted the same so i assume that aint the issue)

Cookiebox.js

```
    var slideWidth = 250;
    var slides = $('#aboutBox').css('width', slideWidth);
    slides.css({
    width: slideWidth,
    height: slides.attr('scrollHeight')
});
var wrapper = slides.wrap('<div>').parent().css({
    width: 1,
    height: slides.height(),
    overflow: 'hidden',
    display: 'none'
});
$('#show').click(function() {
    if(wrapper.is(':visible'))
        return;
    wrapper.show().animate({
        width: '+=' + slideWidth
    }, 'slow');
});
$('#hide').click(function() {
    wrapper.animate({
        width: 1
    }, 'slow', function() {
        wrapper.hide();
    });
});
```

HTML (added right under the body tag)

```
<div id="cookiebox">
<a href="# " title=" " id="show">Cookies</a>
<div id="aboutbox">
<p>We have placed cookies on your computer to make sure this website functions properly.</p>
<p>You can change your cookie settings at any time in your browser settings.</p> 
<p>We'll assume you're OK to continue.</p>
<h2><a href="#" title=" " id="hide">OK</a></h2>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#cookiebox {
    margin-top:25px;
    float:left;
}

#aboutBox {
    padding: 0px 15px;
    max-width:200px;
    float:left;
    background: rgba( 200, 200, 200, 0.8);
    border:1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
}
#aboutBox h1{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#aboutBox p {
    margin: 15px 0;
}
#aboutBox h2 {
    padding: 10px 0;    
}
```

FYI, i have no idea who made the original jquery code, but it wasn't me.
I have already looked around for over one and a half hour for a fix with no luck.

PS, if anyone knows how to make the bottom border show aswell i'd be very happy :)

Could the use of ajax for another item be the issue? 

Hope someone can see the issue and help me out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to put your code inside a doc.ready function, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // your code here
});
```

That is basically what the onLoad option in your jsFiddle is doing for you.

You could also do this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    // your code here
});
```

but .ready will be faster and work fine

Answer (score 1):

You trying to register to events before DOM is ready
You should wrap your code in `$(documnet).ready`